# Triggers to copy information

Tags: mysql, trigger

I have 2 Tables.

`Bank` (Original Table):

```
ID
Bank_Code
Bank_Transaction
Delete
```

`Bank_History`:

```
ID
Bank_ID
CodeH
TransactionH
```

I need for the `Bank` table to copy into `Bank_History` using triggers. Here is what I have so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Bank_after_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `Bank`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 

    IF NEW.Deleted THEN
        SET @Change_Type = 'DELETE';
    ELSE
        SET @Change_Type = 'EDIT';
END IF;
INSERT INTO Bank_History (bank_id, Change_type) VALUES (NEW.id, @Change_Type); 
END
```

It creates a new record but it doesn't transfer all the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say, "it doesn't transfer all the info" what exactly do you mean? Do you want to insert into the history table before the data is updated AND after for auditing purposes?

> ...the mysql statement delimiter so that you can use the ; statement
>   delimiter within the trigger definition.

Check the MySQL [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) reference section at MySQL for more info.

Either way, try adding he `DELIMITER //` at the beginning and the end.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `Bank_after_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `Bank`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 

    IF NEW.Deleted THEN
        SET @Change_Type = 'DELETE';
    ELSE
        SET @Change_Type = 'EDIT';
END IF;
INSERT INTO Bank_History (bank_id, Change_type) VALUES (NEW.id, @Change_Type); 
END
//
```

I hope this helps.